# How to implement a Linux Device Driver for Data Acquisition Hardware?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, linux-device-driver

I am developing an acquisition device which requires DMA operation to transfer large data frames to the main memory. For now I am assuming the destination is a contiguous memory region so I am allocating it (say 1 MB) at boot time as described in section "Do-it-yourself allocation" from  [ldd2-ch13](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch13.html). The driver can then access that region by calling ioremap().

The current system works as follows:

1. A memory-mapped control register enables a user-space application to Start/Stop the device
2. Upon start, the device begins to transfer the acquired data to the assigned memory region continuously (and circularly) at ~8MB/s.
3. The reserved memory region has the size of two frames in order to employ a [double-buffering technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering).
4. Once a complete frame has been transferred, the device triggers an interrupt.

I have developed a simple char driver which provides a blocking read() function so that the user-space can read a new data frame every time an interrupt is received.

After running a few tests, I realized that the user-space application misses some frames when running the following code:

```
    for(i=0;i<NUM_FRAMES;i++) {

       read(dev_d,buf,FRAME_SIZE);/*Read frame*/

       for(j=0;j<FRAME_SIZE;j++) /*File dump*/
          fprintf(fp,"%d",buf[j]);

        fprintf(fp,"\n");
    }
```

I suspect that the application's process is being put to sleep between two subsequent reads, allowing the device to rewrite the memory location which should have already been read.

Since I have no experience in kernel development I would like to know how is the correct way to implement a driver for such a device in order to ensure synchronization. Basically I am trying to implement a simple shared memory communication for a real-time acquisition device and I need to guarantee that the OS is able to read all the acquired data frames.

Comment: You wrote that the data rate is ~8MB/s, but what is the frame size and hence the frame rate?  Your `read()` rate has to be as fast as that frame rate.  Your "file dump" loop is not efficient.  This is a classic real-time problem: you have to process the data faster than it arrives, or buffer that data.  Network interfaces increase double-buffering to N-buffers or rings.  Maybe you'll have to also use multithreading, i.e. a dedicated input thread that always has a pending `read()` request.

Comment: Try [`splice()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splice_%28system_call%29), and there is [no need](http://linux.die.net/man/2/splice) to use user space.

Comment: The frames are 512 kB long and the reserved memory is 1MB (2 frames). Each frame takes 62.5 ms to be transferred to the main memory at 8 MB/s. I did some tests and I can access to the read() function and memcpy() the whole region at ~200MB/s (without the wait on interrupt). I believe the problem is that the user-space process is probably put to sleep for a long time, long enough for a new frame to be written on top of a still unread frame. I understand this is a classic real-time problem, but what is the correct way to allocate large kernel buffers?

Comment: Also, multi-threading seems like an interesting approach, maybe I will try that.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more about the `splice()` solution? Is that some way to enable the driver to directly write to a specific file without any user-space intervention?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  If you want to transfer to a file, then you open the your *acquisition* device and a file.  You can control the amount of data read/written, so if you know block sizes, you can insert/annotate your own framing.  There is no copying from kernel to user to kernel memory.  The data will go straight from driver to file.  The file can be another device such as a serial port, etc.

Comment: Cool, so my user-space application only needs to redirect the data stream, that is coming from the driver, to a specific file using `splice()`. But does this mean that the driver is continuously being read after `splice()` is called, i.e.: my `read()` function can remain unchanged or do I need to add any extra function to enable this splice mechanism?

Comment: *" I believe the problem is that the user-space process is probably put to sleep"* -- Yes, that is a problem, since you have 513 system calls performing I/O between each `read()`.  The *"novice mistake"* you're making is not realizing the cycles consumed by performing inefficient I/O.  Try `fprintf()`ing just the first 4 bytes, and see if there's still skipped frames.  Then evaluate what kind of actual processing needs to be done, and how long that might take per frame.  **Make sure you have a workable top-level scheme or the big picture before you worry about implementation details.**

Comment: The problem is that if I don't `fprintf()` the whole frame I can't know if some part of it gets skipped or not. I just need to write the acquired frames to a file, and update it continuously. 
I understand `fprintf()` can take some time so I am considering other options.
Do you know if it is possible to make the `splice()` call to read a fixed block size from my device, i.e.: read a whole a frame with one `read()` ? (assuming the `splice()` calls the driver's `read()` function internally)

Comment: Is the `fprintf()` just for debugging, or are you personally going to be reviewing this data in realtime?  Why can't you write each of these frames as **one block** of 512-bytes of raw binary data rather than convert **each byte** to decimal in precious realtime?  That's what I mean about the "big picture": if you're going to save the frames, just save it raw, and then convert it offline or a low-priority background process.  *"Do you know..."* -- I have to admit ignorance about `splice()`. *"read a whole a frame..."*  -- It's **your** driver; you tell us how/when a read request is satisfied!

Comment: Currently, I'm using `fprintf()` to write like 100 frames and later I'm checking the values that were written to the file. However, that is very close to what I want to do in my application, which is to continuously update a file to display it in real-time. But yes, I guess you've made your point and the data doesn't need to be stored in a human-readable ASCII format. 
Regarding `splice()`, I asked because it would be easier to ensure synchronization for the case I've mentioned.

Comment: When you say -"_it's **your** driver,you tell us how/when a read request is satisfied"_- I agree that I set the "**when**" by calling a `wait_event_interruptible()` and wait for an interrupt but the **how**.. I guess it wouldn't be correct to make a `read()` which always returns 512 kBytes even if the caller asked for fewer bytes. That was my question regarding `splice()`: **How to set this granularity **.

Answer (score 2):

You are reading a very very old book. Here the link to the last version of the book (it is just very old): [Linux Device Driver 3 - Memory Mapping](http://tjworld.net/books/ldd3/#CHAPTER15). You can also read the [DMA-API](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API.txt) from the kernel documentation.

To make a kind of synchronization read [Time, Delays and Deferred Work](http://tjworld.net/books/ldd3/#TimeDelaysAndDeferredWork) chapter. You can use the a *waitqueue*. You *wait* on read() and you *wake_up* when new frames are available.

About your code, it is not enough to understand your problem. But, if you think that you need to sleep/wait, you can implement the poll file_operation in your driver and use select() in user-space to ask if there is something to read.

Comment: The blocking read() functions waits for an interrupt and then copies the frame to the user-space buffer. However, since I am missing some frames, i.e.: I read frame1,frame2 , frame4... , I would like to know how to synchronize the communication without stopping the device from writing to the DMA region.

Comment: My read() function  already uses wait_event_interruptible(wq,flag>0) to wait for an interrupt, where "wq" is a wait queue and "flag" is an atomic variable which is incremented inside the interrupt handler function. I believe the problem is that sometimes the user-space program takes excessive time between subsequent reads inside the for() loop and since the device never stops to write to the memory, some frames are never read. One possible solution is to increase the length of the reserved memory region, but I wanted to know if there is a better way to ensure synchronization in this case.

Comment: Obviously, if your consumer process (user space program) is slower than your producer (the driver) sooner or later you lost some data (it depends by the buffer length). Even if you have a process that continuously transfer from the kernel buffer to the user-space buffer you will have the problem (Probably it will never occur because we have GB of memory in user space). It is not a synchronization problem, if you synchronize the program with the driver you will produce 1 frame, cosume 1 frame, but the driver will lost frame anyway if it continuously generates interrupt that you cannot serve

Comment: Of course, but I have checked and the user-space app can keep up with the device's data rate. I can increase the number of buffers and probably solve the problem with that, I just wanted to know if my driver design is correct or if I am making some novice mistake.

Comment: With the information that I have, yes. But code talk better than people :) so, show your code :D